# Integrate whmcs into my cakephp

Tags: cakephp, whmcs

I have a cake app and want to integrate my license of whmcs. Whmcs have installed it ina whmcs folder in the public html folder and my cake files are here too. When run example.com/whmcs I get a cakephp error what am I doing wrong?

All help appreciated

Comment: http://dogmatic69.com/blog/development/7-using-other-apps-with-cakephp-htaccess-config

Answer (score 0):

Try building a CakePHP component and place your whmsc scripts in the vendor directory.

hope this helps

Comment: Anyone tried this cause whmms charge u to change url and license that's only prob thanks guys